# Округление до заданной точности JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В ходе вычислений результат иной раз получается с большим количеством знаков после точки (большая десятичная часть).
Интересует алгоритм округления таких чисел по следующим критериям:
Есть некоторое число, характеризующее максимально допустимое количество знаков в десятичной части числа `n`, равное `4`
Тогда при получении числа `1.6547835` - можно поступить просто `1.6547835.toFixed(n)` - получим `1.6548`.
Все хорошо. Но если в ходе вычислений получилось целое число, то такой прием даст на выходе `1.0000`, что не очень хорошо.
Далее допустим  получилось число `4.00000000005`, вышеприведенный способ даст `4.0000`, а хотелось бы `4`.
В общем нужен алгоритм который будет округлять следующим образом:

```
6.400000000000002 // 6.4    
1.0000000000000004 // 1
5.3424505674 // 5.3425
5 // 5
6.4560000006 // 6.456
```

Я не прошу готовых ответов, формул и функций, направьте ход моих мыслей в нужное русло.

Comment: округление нужно для вычислений или для показа?

Comment: @Grundy, Оно подставляется в `css` функцию `calc`

Comment: тогда в что не так с _на выходе 1.0000_?

Comment: @Grundy, зачем лишнии нулю, если они не нужны? Не красиво :)

Comment: @Grundy, я бы не сказал что прям дубликат... все же колличество знаков до которых нужно округлить в моем случае динамическая величина...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поизвращаться и сделать так))

```js
test(6.400000000000002); // 6.4    
test(1.0000000000000004); // 1
test(5.3424505674); // 5.3425
test(5); // 5
test(6.4560000006); // 6.456

function myround(n, d) {
  var digits = +"1".padEnd(d, "0");
  return Math.round(n * digits) / digits;
}

function test(n) {
  console.log(myround(n, 5));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, про "умножить - разделить" знал для точности, а вот использовать padEnd !?!?!? Даже не знал про него. Век живи век учись.

Comment: @pepel_xD `padEnd` - штука относительно новая (возможно, поэтому вы про неё не слышали), так что если вам важна поддержка старых версий браузеров (а в IE [даже в 11-м](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd#Browser_compatibility) `padEnd` нет), то стоит воспользоваться другим способом построения строки.

Comment: @Regent там нода, так что все нормально.